# Power automate workflows categorise by list

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, power-automate, flow

In Nintex, when creating a new workflow we could easily do by going into the list. That way it is very easy to see how many workflows are bind to a particular list.

However in Power automate, we have to create workflows all in one location that can cause the confusion or difficult to manage if we have many workflows bind/triggered to different SharePoint lists.

Is there any way to identify at first instance what lists workflow is bind/triggered to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the Power automate flows attached to SharePoint list from list view only if you have used the "For a selected item" trigger in a flow.

Also, you cannot customize the "My/Cloud flows" and "Shared with me" pages in Power automate portal - it only shows the flow name, Modified date and flow type.

However, Microsoft recently released a feature using which you can add the columns under Run history on flow details page.

For flows which use triggers from SharePoint connector, you can add column like "{FullPath}" as shown below which shows the name of list. List of columns you can show here changes based on the flow trigger you used.

Apart from this, I don't think there is any way to see which flow is connected to which SharePoint list from UI/browser.

[image]

---

Here's feedback/idea related to same topic, you can vote: [Folder or Categories for Flows](https://ideas.powerautomate.com/d365community/idea/e074f614-3350-ed11-a81b-6045bd7e903d)

Comment: Check if it is possible using Microsoft Power Platform Center of Excellence (CoE) Starter Kit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/guidance/coe/starter-kit

Comment: Thank you Ganesh.